# laravel multiple inserts to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to insert multiple rows of data into a MySQL table, but only the first row is being inserted. Here is the code in my controller.

```
DB :: table("users_has_activities") -> insert
(
array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 1, "time" => $datetime, "value" => 1,
"multiplier" => 1 ),


array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 2, "time" => $datetime, "value" => 1,
"multiplier" => 1 ),

array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 3, "time" => $datetime, "value" => 1,
"multiplier" => 1 )
);
```

I can do it this way but I am looking for a better way.

```
DB :: table("users_has_activities") -> insert
(
array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 1, "time" => $datetime, "value" => 1,
"multiplier" => 1 )
);

  DB :: table("users_has_activities") -> insert
(
array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 2, "time" => $datetime, "value" => 1,
"multiplier" => 1 )
);


DB :: table("users_has_activities") -> insert
(
array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 3, "time" => $datetime,   "value" =>   1,
"multiplier" => 1 )
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass an array, but you forgot to add `array()`:

```
DB::table("users_has_activities") -> insert(array(
array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 1, "time" => $datetime, "value" => 1,
"multiplier" => 1 ),

array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 2, "time" => $datetime, "value" => 1,
"multiplier" => 1 ),

array("usersID" => $userId, "activitiesID" => 3, "time" => $datetime, "value" => 1,
"multiplier" => 1 )
));
```